# Typescript async function generic; How to enforce async function generic with generic return type?

Tags: typescript, generics, promise

I am trying to create a function that retries an async function a number of times before rejecting. I want to maintain the typescript typings of the function to retry and need to figure out how to maintain the return type AND enforce that the passed function is `PromiseLike`.

It is possible to create a retry function that has a typed response inferred from the passed function, but ensuring that the passed function is `PromiseLike` is tricky. If we wrap the `ReturnType<T>` in a promise like below, then we will return a promise of a promise of T, `Promise<Promise<T>>` instead of `Promise<T>`:

```
export async function retry<T extends () => ReturnType<T>>(fn: T, retries: number = 1) {
  let attempts = 0;
  let response: ReturnType<T>;
  
  while (attempts < retries) {
    response = fn();
    try {
      console.log(`Evaluating attempt #${attempts} ...`);
      return await response;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`Attempt #${attempts} failed.`);
      if (attempts < retries) attempts = attempts + 1;
      else return response;
    }
  }
}
```

The core problem I am trying to solve is how to enforce that the generic constraint is an asynchronous function instead of any `Callable`. Using TS utilities such as `Promise` and `PromiseLike` are not possible as the return type will be wrapped twice with a promise (in the case of an asynchronous function).

Comment: You seem to be really overcomplicating that, why not make `T` the _return_ type: https://tsplay.dev/m0bvRw

Comment: Ehh must have been a bit of tunnel vision trying to solve this one, i think that would work well and be less complex. If you want to add that as a solution I will mark it as the answer? @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve this is with `PromiseLike<Awaited<T>>`, this combination will enforce that the passed function is asynchronous. This combo can effectively be though of as a `PromiseLike` constraint when we know that the `T` will be a promise.

```
export async function retry<T extends () => PromiseLike<Awaited<ReturnType<T>>>>(fn: T, retries: number = 1) {
  let attempts = 0;
  let response: PromiseLike<Awaited<ReturnType<T>>>;
  
  while (attempts < retries) {
    response = fn();
    try {
      console.log(`Evaluating attempt #${attempts} ...`);
      return await response;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`Attempt #${attempts} failed.`);
      if (attempts < retries) attempts = attempts + 1;
      else return response;
    }
  }

  throw Error("Invalid number of retries");
}
```